# Regex behaves differently in java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex

My regular expression for url pattern match for java and javascript

```
"(?:http(?:s?)://)?[\\w.]+\\.(?:(?:ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|za|zm|zw)[a-z]?(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z@]|$))[\\w./?&=\\d-]*"


    public static void main(String args[])
{
    String msg="Join us at #ABCD to learn how you can optimize effectiveness in the age of #digital consumer.May 12-14|Vegas http://abcd.at/2025RainR4";
    int finalLength=msg.length();

    String links ="(?:http(?:s?)://)?[\\w.]+\\.(?:(?:ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|za|zm|zw)[a-z]?(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z@]|$))[\\w./?&=\\d-]*";

    Pattern patternLinks = Pattern.compile(links,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcherLinks = patternLinks.matcher(msg);

    while(matcherLinks.find()) 
    {
        System.err.println(matcherLinks.group());
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly in javascript for the following message,

"Join us at #ABCD to learn how you can optimize effectiveness in the age of #digital consumer.May 12-14|Vegas http://abcd.at/2025RainR4"

but in java side consumer.May is also picked up as link which is not true.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use regexes in Java for this purpose; since this is a URI, use the `URI` class and decompose.

Comment: The given test string does not even match the given regex in Java 7, let alone produces any captures. Can you clarify what is the test data and what is the expected result of applying the regex?

Comment: Test data is mentioned message.

"Join us at #ABCD to learn how you can optimize effectiveness in the age of #digital consumer.May 12-14|Vegas http://abcd.at/2025RainR4"

Currently we are using java6

Comment: It does not match using Java 6u45 too. I tested it in javascript and i see that it captures a single group with the value `http://abcd.at/2025RainR4`. You should edit the question and provide all this information.

Comment: Hi Oleg it does generate a match. for your reference I have added java code